# Actioncable failed with WebSocket connection error only in prod env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, redis, actioncable

I'm creating realtime update chat app with Rails(api mode) and react using following technologies.

1.rails 5.2.1
2.puma 3.12.0
3.ruby 2.4.6
4.nginx 1.12.2
5.redis 4.0.10
6.aws elasticache

`frontend/index.js`

```js
import ActionCable from 'actioncable'

ActionCable.createConsumer(`wss://myapp.com:3000/cable?authorization=${tokens['Authorization']}&firebaseUID=${tokens['FirebaseUID']}`)
```

`config/environments/production.rb`

```rb
 config.action_cable.url = 'wss://myapp.com/cable:3000'
 config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://myapp.com', /http:\/\/myapp.*/, 'https://myapp.com', /https:\/\/myapp.*/ ]
```

`nginx.conf`

```
upstream puma {
   server unix:///srv/myapp/tmp/sockets/puma.sock;
}

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @webapp;
 }

location @webapp {
   proxy_read_timeout 300;
   proxy_connect_timeout 300;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_pass http://puma;
 }



location /cable {
   proxy_pass http://puma/cable;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

`config/cable.yml`

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: ENV['ELASTIC_CACHE_URL']}  <= endpoint of elasticache(redis4.0)
```

But I'm getting the following error.

> main.js:89513 WebSocket connection to 'wss://myapp.com:3000/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Can somebody give me advice?

Comment: Did you try ws:// before wss://? did you check your certificates?

Comment: Hi. Nick M  Thank you for reply.   I tried with ws:  but nothing changed

Comment: wss:// prefix means SSL, if you didn’t set up SSL/certificates properly it won’t connect. Anything in the server logs or browser console?